Shopify GraphQL publication products pagination issue
Using PHP I need to take products from specific publication so I write:
$requests = $shop->api()->graph(
'{
  publication(id: "gid://shopify/Publication/11111111") {
    id
    products(first:250) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
                    }           
            }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
        }
    }
}

because there is more than 250 products I need to integrate paginations and to run this again so in the next loop I write:
$requests = $shop->api()->graph(
'{
  publication(id: "gid://shopify/Publication/11111111") {
    id
products(first:250, after:"eyJ111N0X2lkIassssVlIjoiNjg111111111111111111") {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
                    }           
            }
      pageInfo {
        hasNextPage
        endCursor
      }
        }
    }
}

but this time I just got "Server Error" message and no other explanation...
How to implement pagination with publication and products if there is more than 250 products in publication?
